# How do I CSS Style a Table that affects TD as well?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a class to the table, that allows me to style the "td" without having to do something like this:

```
<table class="myStyle"><tr><td="borderthing"></td><td style="borderthing"></td><td="borderthing"></td></tr></table>
```

CSS Wise, I can do:

```
table.myStyle {

}
```

Is there a way I can do:

```
table.myStyle.td {
// borderthing 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the dot. Dots are for classes. Spaces are for descendants. `>` are for first-generation descendants (i.e. children).

```
table.myStyle td {
// borderthing 
}
```

Also, what does this line mean:

```
<td="borderthing"></td>
```

Did you just forget the `class=` attribute? If not, that's completely invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Use the descendant operator (space), or the direct descendant operator (`>`).

```
table.myStyle td { ... }

table.myStyle > tbody > tr > td { ... }
```

The second one will be applied only to cells in the same table if you have nested tables.